# Copy function from user space to kernel and execute

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

First of all, I am doing this for fun so don't judge me.

What I did is passing a function pointer from user space to kernel, copy the function body using copy_from_user to an static array in kernel and start jumping in that array to execute.

in kernel:

```
static char handler_text[PAGE_SIZE] __page_aligned_data;
copy_from_user((void *)handler_text , (const void __user *)my_handler , PAGE_SIZE);
((void (*)())(handler_text))();
```

in user space, what this function does is very simple as follows

```
void my_handler(){
volatile unsigned long * p = (volatile unsigned long *)0xF0000c10;
*p = 0x0000000;
}

10000938 <my_handler>: 
10000938:   3d 20 f0 00     lis     r9,-4096 
1000093c:   39 40 00 00     li      r10,0 
10000940:   61 29 0c 10     ori     r9,r9,3088 
10000944:   91 49 00 00     stw     r10,0(r9) 
10000948:   4e 80 00 20     blr 
1000094c:   00 01 88 08     .long 0x18808
```

**The problem is the first time I do this always generates a Oops. But the second time I do this and there after, the problem is gone and there is no Oops any more.** I can clearly see the function is executed by kernel by reading the memory. I am running a PowerPc target so Oops shows the exception is 700, which is program exception. From the Oops, I can see the instruction dump, where the nip (after) is exactly the same instruction as my_handler.

```
Instruction dump:
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 <3d20f000> 39400000 61290c10 91490000
```

I couldn't figure any sense out of it. Can anyone? Thanks

Comment: If I could put pictures in comments I would put [this](https://media4.giphy.com/media/mxrwSmquLokMw/200_s.gif).

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? Is the kernel-code a custom syscall, i.e. how is it invoked from userspace? Can you provide the full information of the kernel oops? Which Powerpc model?

Answer (score 4):

I hate to discourage an admirable notion, but what you're trying to do is difficult, if not impossible, without some serious extra work.

Your function is linked at location `F` in *user* space. You're copying it to *kernel* space at the location of the static array: `A`. `A` is probably in the kernel's data section, so execution may not be possible. Also, your function is linked at the *wrong* location (e.g. `F != A`).

Further, even if your function could link to the correct location `A`, how are you handling the relocation of symbols within it (e.g. If it calls `printk`, how are you relinking the address inside the function to match the actual `printk` address)?

It is much easier to create a kernel module and load that (via `modprobe`) and you can do whatever you want.

*Side note:* This is a *huge* security vulernability. A similar one was used by the "Stuxnet" worm to penetrate Windows.

---

**UPDATE:**

The dump occurs [in time] long *after* the exception event. By that time, it has the correct data, so the dump shows the *current* state, so to speak, but *not* what happened on the exact cycle in question [due to the nature of this "self-modifying" code].

But, when initially executed it may have had garbage (i.e. the 700). I'm not sure about PPC, but other arches have separate inst and data caches. With out-of-order execution. The data would be in the data cache, but not necessarily in the inst cache [or queue]. And, they tend to operate independently for speed ["Harvard" architecture].

(e.g.) On x86, after setting the static area, you must flush/synchronize so that exec unit refetches the area. Otherwise, it may have already *speculatively* prefetched the instruction data (e.g. it isn't expecting it to be "self-modifying") with data that isn't what is expected [probably 0x00000000].

Consider: After the `copy_from_user` the desired data is in the data cache, but has *not* yet been flushed to RAM. The execution unit [and inst cache], not having any data from the static area, will fetch from RAM. Because self-modifying code is rare, the inst and data caches do *not* snoop each other [it would slow things down].

So, the execution unit got its data from RAM (e.g. 0x00000000) instead of the loaded data [which is *only* in the data cache].

The second time works because the data fetched by the execution unit comes from the data during the first attempt [which has had time to flush to RAM]. That is, the static area has now been populated and the second `copy_from_user` is, effectively, a NOP.

A "post-mortem" dump of the area [as mentioned] would not be able to show this discrepancy.

Comment: Memory protection came to my mind, too, but why should it work the second time?

Comment: @Ctx It's difficult to say without a posting of the function source, build method for it, loading method into kernel, and the code that is _already_ have inside the kernel to allow this. Also, without this context, what does "work the second time" actually mean? It might mean that the OOPS was not a panic and the "second time" was just a NOP [effectively].

Comment: I'm not the OP. But as far as I see it, it should work, if kmalloc'd memory is executable on his platform (The function is PIC and has no external references). Or should never work if it is not executable. Unfortunately, this differs quite from arch to arch.

Comment: @ctx Also, without context, there are many other considerations such as locking, current state before call (with regard to per-CPU, etc.). The kernel is complex enough to require much more information before speculating on this. And, OP stated "static", IIRC, so no `kmalloc`. Preemption of the kernel thread also comes to mind [with restart on different core]. One other thing: kernel code usually has special compiler and linker options that a simple user app doesn't need. So, OP has to be sure to be using them (and is the function coming from a .o or executable?)

Comment: But it's a program exception at a `lis`-instruction, I can't think of a reason why this could fail. If it was a protection violation, an ISI exception (400) should have been generated. Locking, states etc. can not be the reason for an exception for a load register operation. Quite mysterious...

Comment: @Ctx OP isn't checking the `copy_from_user` error return, so ... No proof that the array actually has the program. I'd want a full dump [registers, stack, etc.] in addition to what was provided. The exception may not have been on the `lis` but later (i.e. not "judging", but disbelieving the analysis). What's at `0xF0000c10` in each case? Harmful on 1st and harmless on 2nd? Also, OOPS dumps aren't always definitive. By their nature, they're "best effort", so just one piece of the puzzle.

Comment: The proof is in the oops: `<3d20f000>` <- this is the failed instruction, a `lis     r9,-4096`. This is very reliable.

Comment: @Ctx While normally true, perhaps not here. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, now your answer could explain the observed behaviour (+1).

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. It turned out to be the cache thing. Thanks both Ctx and Craig, I added a

```
flush_dcache_icache_page(virt_to_page((unsigned long)(handler_text)));
```

after

```
copy_from_user((void *)handler_text , (const void __user *)my_handler , PAGE_SIZE);
```

And it is all good now. Before I asked the question, I tried just flush_dcache_page and it didn't work. So I have to flush both dcache and icache to make this work. Thanks again.